# Django Show Files on Disk

Tags: django, file

I want to have a page that will show files from a particular folder on the disk and have the user select one and then "pass" the file path of that file to another view for further processing.  I have no idea where to start, all of my searching turns up uploading files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to display files from one directory on disk, perhaps a simpler solution would be to use the built-in Django [FilePathFeld](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#filepathfield). It will return a path as the value and is represented by a select in forms.

This field isn't for uploading a file, it's only for selecting a pre-existing file.

Comment: This works beautifully except that when I add the forms.FilePathField to the form I'm using to let me select the file it basically saves what is in the path I've given it for path.  No matter what updates in that path it maintains the old list.  I deleted all the files in there to start fresh and could still see the old files list when I went back to the form.  I had to change the path in my forms.py to something different and then change it back to the original path to make it refresh the form list.

Comment: Literally just requires I make any savable change in my forms.py and then refresh the form.html to see the new list of items.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite following you.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/Z3j6E4uEiZY

The exact problem I'm having.  He worded it better

Comment: So you're seeing stale choices... hmm. I haven't run into that issue before, so I'm not sure what the best advice to give is.

Comment: I found something on the Django website where someone said it was an issue 4 years ago and it hasn't been fixed :(  That is very annoying.  I'm going to try to use a different widget.

Comment: Yes that would be. I'll see if I can find a workaround for you.

Answer (score 0):

The only project i know that is still maintained is [django-filebrowser](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser)
The extension is pretty flexible, you can choose to use paths relative to a storage location or absolute server paths.
You should be able to pass the file path to another view by adding the view's path to your form action attribute like this:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="/path/to/view">
  ...
</form>
```